# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Win32.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web, .net-assembly, fileloadexception

I am having problems running my web application.

The project setup is ASP.NET Core web application (.NET Framework). I don't seem to get any Build error. The project doesn't just run.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

[image]

Comment: See also: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/901

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the `System.Net.Http` nuget package.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me after I had updated to Visual Studio 2017 15.4.5 and also updated a load of Nuget packages. I think part of the problem is also using .net framework 4.7.1 as well, which I installed last week...

The fix for me was to remove the dependent assembly from web.config, so just comment out or delete this section:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

In other for me to get it working i uninstalled the Microsoft.Win32.Primitives then installed the exact version which is 4.0. this worked fir me.

Note that there are higher versions but they did not work for me.

Comment: I had to add the `System.Net.Http` nuget package too, then it worked.

Comment: Just adding the nuget package System.Net.Http worked for me.  @tjrobinson, consider adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I accidently deleted my *.suo files and the problem fixed itself. Maybe it was an accident, or irrelevant but i just thought to share it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting .Net 4.7.1 project, I contend that a 4.7.1 versioned Primitives DLL is not available.  Take a look at the properties in Nuget[image]

I believe the Nuget expression would need a > not a = 4.6.

This feels like a hack, but it seemed to work.  If you open Web.config, change this to 4.6[image]